# Change color of text when starting to type

Tags: excel, vba

I have a search function in an excel file where I have a hint in grey color. "Type in word to search for".
I want the hint to be grey as long as it has the default text in cell "D9", but as soon as you start typing something else it should change the color to black. Also if cell "D9" is empty it should fill in the default hint text. I have a solution for everything except the part where it should change to black when I start typing something in "D9".

How can I do this?

This is the code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If [D9].Value = "" Then
    [D9].Value = "Skriv in sökord och tryck enter eller sök"
    [D9].Font.ColorIndex = 15
Else
End If


If [D9].Value = "Skriv in sökord och tryck enter eller sök" Then
    [D9].Font.ColorIndex = 15
Else
    [D9].Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Try conditional formatting to turn the font grey?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to capture changes to the contents of a cell until after you have committed the changes, so you can't change the color as the user types.  If you are ok with changing the color after commit, then you should use the `Worksheet_Change` event for that.

If you must have the color change in real time you should use a `TextBox` and the `KeyDown` or `KeyPress` events

Answer (score 0):

HURRAY! It is possible!!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Set objD9 = Range("D9")

If objD9.Value = "" Then
objD9.Value = "default"
objD9.Font.ColorIndex = 15
ElseIf (objD9.Value <> "default") Then
objD9.Font.ColorIndex = 5
End If

If Not Intersect(Target, objD9) Is Nothing Then
objD9.Value = ""
objD9.Font.ColorIndex = 5
End If
Set objD9=Nothing
End Sub
```